# how to tell in which column the search string was found?

Tags: sql-server, database

is it possible to tell in which column the search string was found, without having to do it with ifs?

```
if <searchstring> in column1
    -- do some stuff here
else if <searchstring> in column2
    ...
...
```

i won't post the exact query, as it is too cryptical and too long, but here's a query which does basically the same

```
select
    title,
    description
from
    position
where
    CONTAINS( (title, description), '"manager"' )
```

Answer (score -3):

You can take help of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.view_name. in this case, like in BOL

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
ORDER BY DATA_TYPE;

Comment: what's in this table? the schemas of the tables used for the search, or the columns that were matched?

Comment: -1 This wouldn't help at all. It appears to return the TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, and DATA_TYPE of all non nullable columns in the database.